# How to define this cron on Google's GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a a cron task which should be fired each half hour:

```
0:30, 1:00, 1:30, 2:00, 2:30 ......... 23:00, 23:30, 0:00
```

How should I write in my cron.yaml file?

Comment: did you even look at the documentation? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Python_app_yaml_The_schedule_format

Comment: @PaulCollingwood Thanks, I've found the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it myself

```
 schedule: every 30 minutes from 0:00 to 23:00
```